# Use PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT function with node-postgres (fastify)

Tags: postgresql, encryption, fastify, node-postgres

I'm trying to use the PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT function to save encrypted data in a PostgreSQL database using Fastify.

The pgcrypto extension has been added using this command 
**CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;**

[image]

I then checked if the extension was successfully added in my DB. 
**SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'pgcrypto' AND extversion IS NOT NULL;**

[image]

In my application.ts, I connect to the postgres db with this connection options:

```
 try {
    
      const connectionObject = {
        database: config.db_name,
        host: config.db_url,
        user: config.db_user,
        password: config.db_pass,
        port: 5432,
        pg: pg
      }
    
      await this.server.register(require('@fastify/postgres'), connectionObject)
      await this.server.pg.query('SELECT NOW()');
    
      console.log('DATABASE CONNECTED')
      
    } catch(error){
    
      console.error("CONNECTION ERROR", error);
    }

    await this.server.ready()
```

The database is connecting without any problem. Then, in my route.ts, I have a POST request that takes some data from a form, and I'm trying to insert this data with a column encrypted, just like that:

```
server.post(
  "/api/v1/api-name", 
  async function(request: any, reply: any) {
  
      try {

          ...
          // GET THE DATA
          // EXECUTING SOME CHECK ON DATA VALIDITY
          ...


          await server.pg.query(`
              INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name (data1, data2, data3, data3, data5, data6)
              VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT($6 ::text, $7 ::text))
          `, [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, config.secretKey]);

          return reply.code(201).send({
              statusCode: 202
          })

      } catch(error: any) {

          return reply.code(500).send({
              statusCode: 500,
              message: error.message
          })
      }
  }
);
```

But I receive this error when I execute the POST request
**function pgp_sym_encrypt(text, text) does not exist**

Executing the query directly from dbeaver, the data is inserted and with the column encrypted

Comment: What is the exact command being executed directly on dbeaver?

Comment: @jjanes 

`INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name (name, lastname, birthdate, birthplace, residence, fiscal_code)
VALUES ('name', 'lastname', NOW(), 'birthplace', 'residence', PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('XXXXXX00A00A000A', 'secret_key'))`